# How can I get Synapse Notebook to only process newly added data?

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have data that I plan on uploading to an Azure storage account. My plan is to create a pipeline in Synapse Studio, which will include an Apache Notebook (Using PySpark). The primary objective is to have the Notebook process the data and then save it to a lake database.

The data will be uploaded to an Azure storage container following this format for example: `2022/Week1/Week1.xlsx` and `2023/Week10/Week10.xlsx`. Initially, I will store and process all historical data in the storage account. After that, the data will be processed and added to the lake database on a weekly basis. Now, the question is, what is the most efficient method to enable the Azure pipeline or the Notebook to identify and process only the newly added data?.

Comment: How do you identify new data? Do you mean an excel file that has a different name to files that are already uploaded? The normal process is that you "queue" your files in a source folder, and once they are ingested, you move those files to a "processed" folder, so they aren't waiting to be ingested any more.

Comment: Yes so new data would be data that has just been added and has not been processed yet. What are the steps that you would typically follow?. Are you using a Pipeline for this action?

Comment: You need to be very specific about "not processed yet". Can you comfirm that we are just ensuring that we do not "reprocess" any file that has the same name as something that has "already been processed"? In that case you just need to use the folder queueing process that I already mentioned. Wherever you are importing files from, you need to move files into a different folder after successful processing. Then next time you run the process, the file won't be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample pattern you could use to ensure you don't import the same file twice.

This uses folders to enforce the state of files.

Create these folders (in ADLS)

- Waiting
- Processing
- Archive
- Failed

Now when your pipeline executes it needs to do the following:

1. Copy all files from *Waiting* to *Processing*
2. Process all files found in *Processing*
3. If the file processed succesfully move it to *Archive*
4. If the file did not process succesfully, move it to *Failed*

The way this works is, any files to be imported should be copied into the *Waiting* folder

After you execute the pipeline every file in the *Waiting* folder should have been moved out, and therefore *won't* be processed again when you run the pipeline again

After execution, files existing in these folders have these meanings

*Waiting* - A new file arrived during the ingestion process and will be processed next time

*Processing* - something went wrong with your processing step - you need to investigate

*Archive* - the file was processed and won't be processed again

*Failed* - the file was specifically noted as failed. You need to fix the issue and probably put the file back in *Waiting* for reprocessing.

These are just suggested folder names - use whatever you like

Comment: I really like the idea here. I'll be sure to give it a go. Just out of curiosity is this a common practice (having separate folders for different stages)?

Comment: Absolutely. I was using this pattern 25 years ago with a tool called DTS (an ancient precursor for Synapse pipelines)